# SKScene and Swift Files are not linking

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

In my xcode project I am trying to transition from one SKScene to another. What triggers the transition is the touching of a SKLabelNode. All of that is working correctly. But after the scene changes none of my code from my class that controls the "StartScence.sks" works. It seems as if my "StartScene.swift" and my "StartScene.sks" are not linked.

This is the code in my GameScene,

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var isTouched: Bool = false
var booleanTouched: Bool!
let ns = SKScene(fileNamed: "StartScene")
let crosswf = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(2)


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    let backgroundimage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ipbg")
    backgroundimage.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    backgroundimage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
    addChild(backgroundimage)

    let playButton = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "")
    playButton.name = "play"
    playButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2 + 100)
    playButton.text = "Play"

    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)
    let run = SKAction.runBlock({


        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))

        switch(randomNumber){

        case (0):

            playButton.fontColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        case 1:

            playButton.fontColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        case 2:

            playButton.fontColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

        case 3:

            playButton.fontColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        default: print("default")


        }

    })

    addChild(playButton)
    var repeatActionForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([wait, run]))
    runAction(repeatActionForever)
    backgroundimage.zPosition = 1
    playButton.zPosition = 2



}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)


    if (touchedNode.name == "play"){

        scene!.view?.presentScene(ns!, transition: crosswf)

    }else{


    }


}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

}

And this is the code that is my "StartScene.swift" that isnt controlling the "StartScene.sks" properly.

```
import SpriteKit

class StartScene: SKScene {


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    print("Scene Loaded")

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two things to be aware of.

1. In your code you are currently loading your .SKS file like this

   ```
   let ns = SKScene(fileNamed: "StartScene")
   ```

Your new scene will load, as all SKS Files are of the class SKScene. 
But, it will only use code from that class.

If you want it to load with the code in your class StartScene, a subclass of SKScene. Change the line to this

```
    let ns = StartScene(fileNamed: "StartScene")
```

2. We can also make the SKS File have a custom class instead of it's default SKScene. So when it's loaded it uses a custom class.

Open the SKS File in Xcode so you can give the scene a Custom Class. In the scene editor and with nothing selected. Click in the utilities area, switch to the Custom Class Inspector, which is the last tab on the right.

Give it a Custom Class of StartScene.

It should work.